# Prove $xf(x)$ is not surjective

Tags: real-analysis, linear-transformations

> Let $K$ be the space of bounded, continuous real-valued functions $f$ from $(0, 1) \to \Bbb R$. Let $K$ have the supremum norm. Let $L: K \to K$ be defined by $L(f)(x) = x f(x)$. Show that $L$ is not surjective.
>
> Answer: There is no such $f \in K$ such that $xf(x) = 3$.

I am confused because if we let $f(x) = 6$ which is a bounded, continuous real-valued function, and let $x = \frac{1}{2} \in (0, 1)$, then we get $L(f(x)) = L(f(\frac{1}{2})) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 6 = 3$. Why is the given counter-example an answer to why this is not surjective?

Comment: Since $L(f)(\frac{2}{3}) = \frac{12}{3} =4 \neq 3$.

Comment: You are on a space of functiosn, so $L(f)(x) = xf(x)$ hold for all $x$, your example only holds for $x=1/2$ but not for $x=1/10$.

Comment: I think that they should have said "$x f(x) = 3$ for all $x$."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there was a continuous function $f:(0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $xf(x) = 3$ it would have to be equal to $f(x) = 3/x$ an hence unbounded.

Answer (score 3):

There is no function $f(x)$ such that $xf(x)$ is the constant function 3. You only gave an example where $xf(x)$ equals 3 at a particular point.

Comment: this ambiguity is why I prefer = to refer to a point and $\equiv$ to refer to _function_ equality (alternatively could have said $g(x)=xf(x)$ and required $g=3$